# How to export power bi report to pdf from mvc application on button click

Tags: powerbi

My client wants the power bi report in PDF format from website.
I don't find rest api to export report to Pdf.
can anyone help me to find solution to this? And please clarify me is this is possible from website?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A public preview of this API is [planned for February 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/business-intelligence/api-export-report-powerpoint-pdf-jpeg).

> **Feature details**
>
> Developers will be able to provide their users with the option to export their data in PowerPoint, PDF, and JPEG formats in two main scenarios:
>
> - **Interactive mode**: End users interact with a report and export their own view of the data.
> - **Non-interactive mode**: Offline generation of snapshots distributed to different people in the organization.
>
> The following capabilities will be supported:
>
> - Export report for both Power BI and non-Power BI users (SaaS and PaaS embed scenarios)
> - Export user context (the screenshot will include applied filters, cross filters, etc.)
> - Export including row-Level security (RLS)
> - Export a single page or entire report